# Visual studio is still displaying errors for a file that I already deleted

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

A file was displaying errors: `Too many characters in character litteral`. So I deleted the aspx file. When, when I compile the application, it's compile fine. However, when I open the Erros windows, I still see those errors there and they supposed to be thrown from the page I've already deleted.

Any way to fix the problem?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's a real error, if you have indeed deleted that file already.

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete all the temp files from the Temporary folders in Windows/Microsoft.Net/ Framework and Framework64/TemporaryInternetFiles

Open Visual Studio and reload your solution. If you still see errors and that file is still part of your solution.

On my system one of the paths is like this : "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files".

When you compile an application the code gets deployed in one of the 32 or 64 bit folders. This allows the code to run quickly without recompilation if nothing has changed from the previous run. This is usually one of the sources of issues like the one you are seeing. You think you've removed something but old code is still present there in the temp folder.

Comment: I don't see `TemporaryInternetFiles` folder following the path you gave. However, under `v4.0.30319` folder, I see `Temporary ASP.NET files`. Inside that folder, the only folder present is `tfs`.

Comment: I added more info to my answer. To be honest I expected the Visual Studio restart to fix your issue, sometimes errors do appear in there even though you fixed the source of the problem and the restart usually fixes that.

Comment: The first time I had to restart the computer for the errors to disappear. Now, just restarting Visual Studio has been enough. What's interesting is the fact that only this error is being displayed. The other types of errors disappear after they've been fixed.

Comment: I did not find any of the folders you two mentioned above. But restarting repaired everything, thank~~

Comment: wow, I don't even remember this answer .... 2016 ... been a while since :)